# Count up/down Array animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, counter

I want to create an count up and down animation with an Array when pressing left & right arrow.

I have 3 arrays, each arrow will be linked to an ID.

```
var KEY = {
  LEFT: 37,
  RIGHT:  39
}

$(function(){
  $(document).keydown(function(e){
    switch(e.which){
      case  KEY.RIGHT:
        // Arrays +1

      break;
      case  KEY.LEFT:
        // Arrays -1

      break;
    }
  });
});

var asiel = [0, 200, 300, 900, 1100, 2000];   

var nareiziger = [0, 200, 300, 900, 1100, 2000];   

var total = [0, 200, 2590, 9000, 11000, 23000];
```

DEMO: [codepen](https://codepen.io/jstronk/pen/JOjVbm)

I don't really know how to proces it.

How do i do that?

Thanks a lot for you help already!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a workling fiddle. Just define a new variable with the positon and count it up and down.

[Working Fiddle](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gXOyqw)

```
var KEY = {
  LEFT: 37,
  RIGHT:  39
}
var asiel = [0, 200, 300, 900, 1100, 2000];   

var nareiziger = [0, 200, 300, 900, 1100, 2000];   

var total = [0, 200, 2590, 9000, 11000, 23000];   

$(function(){
  let pos = 0
  changeVal()
  function changeVal(){
  $("#asiel").html(asiel[pos])
  $("#total").html(total[pos])
  $("#nareiziger").html(nareiziger[pos])
  }
  $(document).keydown(function(e){
    switch(e.which){
      case  KEY.RIGHT:

        pos < total.length ? pos += 1
        : pos = total.length

        changeVal()
        // Arrays +1

      break;
      case  KEY.LEFT:
        pos > 0 ?
        pos -= 1
        : pos = 0

        changeVal()
        // Arrays -1

      break;
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: This looks great, but is it also possible to get this like really counting. 
Now its springs from 0 to 200 for example.

Comment: dont know what you are meaning. The first item is 0 the next is 200 in the array

Comment: With the count up animation im looking for something like this: https://inorganik.github.io/countUp.js/

but it has to count up to the numbers that are placed in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the hang of arrays and indices it is not so hard. Take a look:

introduces a new variable: `counter`

It gets a new value every time user hits left or right.
Test if the index is in the array.

At the end of the function reflect the counter using `array[index]`.

```js
var KEY = {
  LEFT: 37,
  RIGHT:  39
}
var counter = 0;

$(function(){
  $(document).keydown(function(e){
    switch(e.which){
      case  KEY.RIGHT:
        // Arrays +1
        asiel.length == counter ? counter = asiel.length -1 : null;
        counter++;    
      break;
      case  KEY.LEFT:
        // Arrays -1
        counter--;
        0 > counter ? counter = 0 : null;
      break;
    }
    $("#asiel").text(asiel[counter]);
    $("#nareizigers").text(nareiziger[counter]);
    $("#total").text(total[counter]);
  });
});

var asiel = [0, 200, 300, 900, 1100, 2000];   

var nareiziger = [0, 200, 300, 900, 1100, 2000];   

var total = [0, 200, 2590, 9000, 11000, 23000];
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12 data">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div id="datum">
     <h1>Maart 2015</h1>
     
    </div>
   </div>
   
    
    <div class="col-sm-3">
     <div class="asiel">
      <h3 class="white-h3" >
       + <span id="asiel">0</span>
      </h3>
      <div class="subtitel">
       Eerste asielzoekers
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="eerste-asiel">
      <h3 class="white-h3" >
       + <span id="nareizigers">127</span>
      </h3>
      <div class="subtitel">
       Nareizigers
      </div>
     </div>
    </div> <!-- // colomn-2 -->
    <div class="col-sm-4">
     <div class="asiel">
      <h3 class="white-h3" id="total">
       29.301
      </h3>
      <div class="subtitel">
       Totaal aantal syrische immigranten sinds januari 2013
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Works well! But is it also possible to make the numbers look like a count up.
For example like this: https://inorganik.github.io/countUp.js/

Comment: Yes that is possible, but that would require a whole lot of coding and I'm not for hire. This site is only to solve coding problems.